# Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM when using node-gradle plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, next.js, yarn-v2, gradle-node-plugin

I want to use [Gradle Plugin for Node](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) to package my Spring Boot REST api and yarn based Next.js frontend project.

I have read a lot on the Net and found:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    // Gradle frontend
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.5.1"

}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    // Frontend
    implementation 'com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:3.5.1'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

node {
    version = '18.13.0'
    yarnVersion = '1.22.19'
    download = true
    nodeProjectDir = file("${project.projectDir}/src/frontend")
}

tasks.withType(NodeTask).configureEach {
    npmCommand = false
    yarnCommand = true
}

tasks.register('yarnInstall', YarnTask) {
    args = ['install']
}

tasks.register('yarnBuild', YarnTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

tasks.register('cleanFrontend', Delete) {
    delete 'src/frontend/.next'
    delete 'src/frontend/node_modules'
}

tasks.register('copyFrontend', Copy) {
    from 'src/frontend/.next'
    into 'src/main/resources/static'
}

clean.dependsOn(cleanFrontend)
yarnBuild.dependsOn(yarnInstall)
copyFrontend.dependsOn(yarnBuild)
processResources.dependsOn(copyFrontend)

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'
```

but above configuration gives me logs as:

```
2023-03-13T14:54:11.725+0500 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :yarnBuild
2023-03-13T14:57:43.440+0500 [QUIET] [system.out] info  - Compiled successfully                                       
2023-03-13T14:57:43.674+0500 [QUIET] [system.out] info  - Collecting page data...

2023-03-13T14:57:43.617+0500 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :yarnBuild 
2023-03-13T14:58:57.532+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
2023-03-13T14:58:57.558+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] warn  - Restarted collecting page data for [object Object] because it took more than 60 seconds
2023-03-13T14:58:57.559+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] warn  - See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout

2023-03-13T14:58:58.089+0500 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger]                   
2023-03-13T14:58:58.089+0500 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :yarnBuild 
2023-03-13T14:59:58.704+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
2023-03-13T14:59:58.705+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
2023-03-13T14:59:58.709+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
2023-03-13T14:59:58.713+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]                                                                      
2023-03-13T14:59:58.713+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] > Build error occurred                                               
2023-03-13T14:59:58.717+0500 [ERROR] [system.err] Error: Collecting page data for [object Object] is still timing out after 2 attempts. See more info here htt
ps://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-data-collection-timeout
2023-03-13T14:59:58.717+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at onRestart (SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:605:3
5)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.718+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at Worker.isPageStatic (SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\lib\worker
.js:70:40)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.718+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.718+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\
trace.js:79:20)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.719+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:737:52    
2023-03-13T14:59:58.719+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\
trace.js:79:20)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.720+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async Promise.all (index 4)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.720+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:676:17    
2023-03-13T14:59:58.720+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\trace\
trace.js:79:20)
2023-03-13T14:59:58.720+0500 [ERROR] [system.err]     at async SpringProjects\demo\src\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:629:170   
2023-03-13T14:59:58.808+0500 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock]
```

Full stacktrace is:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting your instructions from but there's a few weird sections

First of all, NodeTask has neither `npmCommand` nor `yarnCommand`

```
tasks.withType(NodeTask).configureEach {
    npmCommand = false
    yarnCommand = true
}
```

Secondly, there's already a generated `yarnInstall` task so you shouldn't need:

```
tasks.register('yarnInstall', YarnTask) {
    args = ['install']
}
```

And third, since you're using the `plugins {}` block you don't need to apply the plugin using the old syntax, so you can remove: `apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'`

Additionally, since you have it in the `plugins {}` block you already have a dependency on the plugin, you don't need the `implementation 'com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:3.5.1'` (which is on the wrong level anyways, it should be part of the `buildscript {}` section when using the legacy plugin setup)

And then for the actual problem, if you look after the `[system.err]` you're actually getting the real error message, without knowing the project setup my best recommendation is try running yarn manually from the same directory as your `build.gradle`